# Large scale studies on the accuracy of injections for tennis elbow: do they confirm the injection accuracy is only ~30%?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis, injections

​I am (negatively)​ impressed by the result of (1) published last week: they quantified how often injections for tennis elbow are correctly localized. Only 3 out of 10 were!

> ​Result details:​
>
> ​Of the 10 performed injections, only 3 injections (30 %) were at least partially located at the ECRB (extensor carpi radialis brevis) tendon. Six (60 %) out of 10 injections were also located intra-articular. Six injections were located (totally or partially) at the ECRL (extensor carpi radialis longus) tendon. The acrylic dye was also located at the anconeus muscle (n = 3), lateral epicondyle (n = 3), triceps muscle (n = 2), brachioradialis muscle (n = 1). The number of perforations ranged from 1 to 10 and the amount of injected fluid ranged from 1 to 2 cc.

Are there any similar studies (ideally of larger scale) confirming that surprisingly low injection accuracy for tennis elbow?  I am mostly interested in both medical and lateral epicondylitis (a.k.a. epicondylopathy, tennis/golfer elbow, enthesopathy, enthesopathy of the ECRB), but also curious about other tendinopathies.

---

- (1) Keijsers, R et al. Knee Surg Sports Traumatol Arthrosc (2016). Injection of tennis elbow: Hit and miss? A cadaveric study of injection accuracy
  doi:10.1007/s00167-016-4212-0 ; http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00167-016-4212-0 ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1007/s00167-016-4212-0

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.